# Y-position issue with rect while ceating 1 SVG element per div with JQuerySVG and Raphael.js

Tags: jquery, svg, raphael, jquery-svg

Well, since someone downvoted this instead of trying to ask for a change, I am going to change up my question to better make sense.

so here are some pics of what's going on.

http://imageshack.com/a/img633/2685/7UYA8e.png

http://imageshack.com/a/img905/8505/u0gI9U.png

http://imageshack.com/a/img538/7152/gV5jd9.png

Basically I am trying to use SVG to create rectangles as well as images and then manipulate them with the DOM and do things like drag.

Instead of having 1 SVG Root or w/e you want to call it, I have multiple ones, as in 1 SVG per div.

On Raphael when I went from 1 "paper" to multiple ones(it seemed like doing document.create(div) was causing issues as well and that an already created div worked). I get what is going on with JQuery SVG when "configure({height})" is set, which is the positions of my objects are messed up at lower amounts i.e., if my height is 1 it will be messed up, but if it's 100 it will be in place.  It will mess up by going to positions farther down the page than it should, which can be seen in the images above.

If I have 1 paper in Raphael this doesn't happen, as well as if configure is off in JquerySVG; however if Configure is off, at some point (which can be seen in Image 1) I get my rectangles cut off, because my viewport isn't correct (thus needing configure to BE ON).

Raphael doesn't seem to have this cut off issue, which seems to be from what I gather from here http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-viewport-view-box.html

> The second example has preserveAspectRatio set to xMinYMin slice. That will preserve aspect ratio, but scale the view box according to the larger aspect ratio (the x-axis with ratio 2), resulting in an image too big to fit within the viewport. The image is said to be "sliced".

If anyone has any recommendations on what I might be doing wrong I would appreciate it, but I'm not sure why I am having these issues.

I hope the pics suffice, because this is very annoying and I just want to know how to do what I need to without having issues....

My code

```
   var scale = ....
      for(var i = 0; i < total; i++)
      {
       var face = document.createElement("div");

        face.id = 'face'+i;       


        document.getElementById('plan').appendChild(face);

      $('#face'+i).svg();

        var faceE = $('#face'+i).svg('get'); 


         //   faceE.configure({width: w*scale, height: h*scale}, true);   

        faceE.rect(0,0,w*scale,
                   h*scale,{fill:'black', stroke: 
                   'red', strokeWidth: 0.3*scale});

    $( '#face'+i ).draggable({ snap: true});

         $('#face'+i).css({position:"absolute", left: x*scale, top:y*scale, width: w*scale, height:h*scale}); 

}
```

I'll try to make a fiddle later and hopefully I can get some results.  is JQuery SVG part of Fiddle or do I need to do something special for it?

Comment: Remember that SVG is a language then I don't think that it's a problem with it.

Comment: I think you need to narrow the problem down to a specific isolated problem people can look at on the question. I've been to 3 different pages, one with an accepted answer, so its difficult to actually see a running example of the problem. I would suggest putting a simple jsfiddle highlighting the problem, instead of referencing other questions.

Comment: I changed my post, to make ti seem easier. I know I wrote a lot, but I don't know why people have to downvote, without even trying to help out. 

The questions I referenced were my own because this is an ongoing issue, but I realized this probably confuses everything as I was trying to isolate it for a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the divs.

It will be faster if you generate the svgs pure from the server side whatever server code you are using.

Here I wrote you an example using Raphael but again from what read you don't need it.

```
var rows = 5;
var columns = 5;
var space = 5;
var rectWidth = ($(document).width()-((rows+1)*space))/rows;
var rectHeight = ($(document).height()-((columns+1)*space))/columns;
var p = [];
var y = 0;

for(i=0;i<rows;i++) {
  for(z=0;z<columns;z++) {
    p[y] = Raphael((i*rectWidth)+((i+1)*space),(z*rectHeight)+((z+1)*space),rectWidth,rectHeight);
    p[y].rect(0,0,p[y].width,p[y].height).attr({fill:"red", stroke: "black","fill-opacity": ((i+1)*0.1) + ((z+1)*0.1)});
    p[y].canvas.setAttribute('id', 'svg'+y);
    $('#svg'+y).draggable({snap: true});
    y++;
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/crockz/35ab0k19/

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I really appreciate it!

I am using JQuerySVG now, but I appreciate the example greatly, as I have learned from it!

As for server side I am using JSON with an Ajax call.

  $.getJSON('test.json', function(data)
  {
  }


It's interesting that we are getting rid of the divs, and from what I see you are using the HTML5 Canvas?  This seems a lot easier and less code to create!  I am new to web dev so I'm not up on all the latest stuff so I appreciate the advice!

Also, do you know what is causing the issues?  The div's themselves?  Hope this works!

thanks so much!!!

Comment: Use just the enough amount of code that you need, not a bit more.
If you can generate the pure svgs with php or ruby, you save resources for advanced behaviors such as scaling and dragging on the client side.

Comment: Am I using more than I need now?

Originally I was working with JSP on the server side, but found that using JSON and ajax would work better, and I thought faster than having to contact my server for things.  I don't know PHP or Ruby.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: I was just talking about the divs, I don't know enough to make any assumptions about your approach, sometimes it's better if you can have half the job done on the server before the page loads on the browser, or you can do it all with just static html and css.

Comment: Thanls i'm pretty new to web dev so I'm still learning how to do what.  Originally I was using a pojo to read a file, adn then server it to my jsp page while using EL to fill up the elements.  I want to be able to use ajax to refresh the elements when clicking a menu option.  i.e., one option is to change the rectangles to images.  They will all be rectangles as well, but I need to be able to switch quickly.  My original approach refreshed the page, so I went to do it through JS and now I just use $.getJSON to get a JSON file, load it and manip with js all the way.  Not too sure is a good way.

Comment: I wanted to say everything worked... Thanks!!

One thing I noticed with this line in my code

p[y] = Raphael((i*rectWidth)+((i+1)*space),(z*rectHeight)+((z+1)*space),rectWidth,rectHeight);

I was making the width and height larger than they should be, and I noticed all of the rectangles moved down, just like what was happening in JquerySVG with configure: ON.

What's interesting is that when I added extra height and width to the SVG it FIXED the problem, but in Raphael it actually CREATES the problem?  What the hell is going on lolol :(.

It also seems that I cannot do this in JquerySVG.